# How can I switch back to interactive in Ionic CLI?

Tags: ionic-framework, npm, ionic3

When using Ionic, the --no-interactive flag is automatically applied in every command and its very frustrating.

For example, when running `ionic start`, I get

> --no-confirm: Integrate your new app with Cordova to target native iOS and Android? No

According to the documentation, this should have been a prompt and allowed me to select yes but it selects "no" without prompt. The only thing I could find in the documentation is this:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/configuring.html

> Flags CLI flags are global options that alter the behavior of a CLI
>   command.
>
> --help: Instead of running the command, view its help page.
>
> --verbose: Show all log messages for debugging purposes.
>
> --quiet: Only show WARN and ERROR log messages.
>
> --no-interactive: Turn off interactive prompts and fancy outputs. If a CI server is detected (we use ci-info), the CLI is automatically non-interactive.
>
> --confirm: Turn on auto-confirmation of confirmation prompts. Careful: the CLI prompts before doing something potentially harmful. Auto-confirming may have unintended results.

But I'm not sure what a CI server is or how that would have been enabled since this is a fresh install. I tried unisntalling NPM completely, deleting my AppData npm folders and reinstalling but this doesn't solve the problem.

Per this question I tried another solution:

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/2744

```
ionic config set -g interactive true
```

This modified my global ionic config file but didn't change the outcome. I still have --no-confirm on my `ionic start` command.

Comment: so do you want it to be interactive or not? based on your question you want to re-enable interactivity but then you do global config change calling interactive false? sorry a bit confusing what you really want. Can you re-state your question?

Comment: Sorry, that's just a typo when I was typing up my question. Setting interactive to true does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out the issue is that my terminal (git bash in this case because powershell doesn't work for some of the stuff I needed to use) didn't support interactive. It would be much more convenient if the error message from Ionic was more specific. My solution was to uninstall windows because it's a crap OS for developers, install Ubuntu, and use the native terminal which works perfectly.

I suppose anyone coming in from Google with the same issue could switch from git bash to Powershell if just for this one operation, but there's a lot of interaction with ionic so you're basically stuck with Powershell instead of git bash.

Answer (score 2):

Me too faced this issue on windows with git bash. I started using windows command prompt and it works !!